# What is the best way to pass data between two components which don't have parent-child relation in Angular 13

Tags: angular

What is the best way to pass data between two components which don't have parent-child relation in Angular 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Shared service.**

Shared service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MessageService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(message: string) {
        this.subject.next({ text: message });
    }

    onMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Component A

```
export class ComponentA implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    isAlive = true;

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.messageService.onMessage()
          .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)).subscribe(message => {
            // Do anything
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.isAlive = false;
    }
}
```

Component B

```
export class ComponentB {
    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

    sendMessage(): void {
        // send message to subscribers via observable subject
        this.messageService.sendMessage('Hello!');
    }
}
```

**2. Ngrx store**

Ngrx is bit complex and may be too much for small projects. Here is the [complete documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store).

**3. LocalStorage or SessionStorage**

Depending on your requirement you can use these storages. But they are not like observables. Therefore, if a new value available, they don't knock. You have to manually check the storage for new values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little example, this example shares the value of current theme of page to any component

```
component1.html

<div (click)="switchTheme()"></div>
```

---

```
component1.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SwitcherService } from 'services/switcher.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  templateUrl: './component1.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component1.scss']
})
export class component1 implements OnInit {
  currentTheme: any;

  constructor(private sw: SwitcherService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.applyCurrentLayoutSettings();
  }

  applyCurrentLayoutSettings() {
    // here is the theme
    this.sw.getCurrentThemeObservable().subscribe( (theme: any) => this.currentTheme = theme );
  }

  switchTheme() {
    const invertedTheme = this.invertTheme();
    this.sw.switchCurrentTheme(invertedTheme);
  }
  
  invertTheme() {
    return this.currentTheme == 'dark' ? 'light': 'dark';  
  }
```

---

```
switcher.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SwitcherService {
  private currentThemeSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  private currentTheme: Observable<any>;

  constructor() { 
    if( !this.getCurrentTheme() ) { this.setCurrentTheme('dark'); }

    this.currentThemeSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.getCurrentTheme());
    this.currentTheme = this.currentThemeSubject.asObservable();

  }
  
  switchCurrentTheme(theme: string) {
    this.setCurrentTheme(theme);
    this.currentThemeSubject.next(theme);
  }

  getCurrentThemeValue() {
    return this.currentThemeSubject.value;
  }

  getCurrentThemeObservable() {
    return this.currentTheme;
  }

  getCurrentTheme() {
    return localStorage.getItem('currentTheme');
  }

  setCurrentTheme(theme: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentTheme', theme);
  }
}
```

---

```
component2.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SwitcherService } from 'services/switcher.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component2',
  templateUrl: './component2.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component2.scss']
})

export class component2 implements OnInit {
  currentTheme: any;
  constructor(private sw: SwitcherService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // here is the theme
     this.sw.getCurrentThemeObservable().subscribe( (theme: any) => this.currentTheme = theme );
  }
}
```